Unable to call https request in Angular
enter image description hereI am using the httpService to get data from an mock api, but it throws error
I am using a service
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WishService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getWishes(){
    return this.http.get('https://6697ee3602f3150fb66f83cb.mockapi.io/api/v1/wishItem')
  }
}

and then I am injecting the service into my app component
  constructor(events: EventService, private wishService: WishService) {
    events.listen('removeWish', (id: any) => {
      const index = this.items.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.wishService.getWishes().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.items = data;
    });
  }

but I receive error in my browser
I might be missing something I guess, can someone help me out?
since I am on the latest version of Angular, for me httpsClientModule is depreceated and I do not have an app.module.ts file, I didn't get much information to solve it and the docs were not that helpful because I didnt understand what it required me to do.

You need to use provideHttpClient

This question is similar to: Angular 16 standalone app: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

yeah, it works, thank you @JSONDerulo

As mentioned before, you need to use provideHttpClient. Here's a link to a blog which shows how to do it in the newer version of Angular Angular http in standalone components
